# Angular-Slickgrid | How to get the sum of a column outside the datagrid?

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

What would be the best way to take the total value of a column and send it to a component or external variable?
Something like this for example:

[image: Example total sum]

I tried to find an example on the wikis or a similar issue here but I didn't find it, I apologize if it exists.

Comment: There's no easy (magic) code to doing that, you're trying to get a Group Total without using Grouping. The options that you have available would be to use Grouping, like [Example 14](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/grouping) or calculate it yourself. There's also this SlickGrid [Example - Footer Totals](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-footer-totals.html) that I never created a demo in my lib for, it should be doable still (but again it's not really what you're looking for). There's no auto-magic of any kind, you need to code it

Comment: Your question is also similar to this other Stack Overflow question [Using SlickGrid Aggregation/ Sum of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951253/using-slickgrid-aggregation-sum-of-a-column)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.